# How to make info collected in an application persistent in iOS/iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, persistence

I am developing an iPhone application where I collect info from the user when he/she uses it for the first time. I store this in a singleton class as I need it throughout my app. Now I want this class to be persistent, as I don't want to collect this information if the app is closed and started again. How can I save this class?

Comment: you can use sqlite database or `NSUserDefault` to store values or save detail in a file and save that to application user area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

U may use :NSUserDefaults"
To write:

```
NSString* str = @"StringToSave";
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects: @"array", @"to", @"save",nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: str forKey:@"stringSetting"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: arr forKey:@"this_is_array"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

To read:

```
NSString* str = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"stringSetting"];
NSArray *a = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"this_is_array"];
```

Answer (score 1):

NSUserDefaults is perfect for this as long as you aren't talking a large amount of data.  I use it to store user's information (networkid, lastlogin, etc).

Answer (score 0):

use a SQLITE database or the `NSUserDefaults` class.
Both solutions stores your data, untill you completelly delete the app.
If you still want to use that data even when the user deletes the app and re-installs it, I'd consider using a webservice with mySQL in the back.

Answer (score 0):

Either save it to the local storage (file, core data) or synchronize with your remote server via http.